# Flutter: http response based on model strict type

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement a strict type http request/response. I'm new in flutter but have some experience in typescript. I don't know if I'm doing it right. **Sorry I dont have enough reputation to post the screenshot of my code.**

[Actual screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0c9H.png)

My first issue is on line 21: **"type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Api' in type cast"**. I want to convert the response.body to the same expected response of the login func

Then next is line 31, my concern here is the error variable is a dynamic type that cannot be 'Api' response. Can I make it possible to have to expected response type? or any workaround to this?

I hope someone could help me with this one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you don't return anything from `catch` block. Next you'll need to parse `response.body` which is a `String` to make it `Api<Data>`;

Comment: read https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Answer (score 0):

1. The body is a json, you need to parse it first and create the Api model from it.

```
import 'dart:convert';
...
      var responseData = jsonDecode(restResponse.data); //
      if(responseData is Map){ 
          Data.fromJson(responseData); //you can read the map entries and create a Data entry. 
       }
```

2. You can write a base class as response, and have a success class and an error class, and you can check those from the caller side. I'd suggest to return the parsed json without any model mapping and map the json to model from the caller side.

```
abstract class ResponseBase {}
class ResponseSuccess extends ResponseBase {
   final dynamic data;
   ResponseSuccess(this.data);
}
class ResponseError extends ResponseBase {
   final int statusCode;
   ResponseError(this.statusCode);
}

Future<ResponseBase> login(...
```

And from the caller:

```
whenLoginClicked() async{
 var response = await repository.login(data, devideId);
 if(response is ResponseSuccess){
   // parse the response.data 
  } else if(response is ResponseError){
   // handle error
  }
}
```